# Why does `sudo gnome-text-editor` throw GLib-GIO-CRITICAL error?

Tags: sudo, glib, gnome-text-editor

Whenever I try to launch a system file to edit it using `sudo gnome-text-editor`, I get the error

```
(gnome-text-editor:64141): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 17:47:31.731: g_dbus_connection_emit_signal: assertion 'object_path != NULL && g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
```

This occurs multiple times for each attempt at opening a file.
Why is this?

Comment: Impossible to answer by us. --This is an application bug-- To debug, you need to set `G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals`, then get a backtrace and file a bugreport.  And are you sure it is meant to be started using `sudo`? Probably the problem ;) Generally you use command line editors like nano, vi, vim to edit system files.

Comment: Because `sudo` doesn't work with graphical programms.

Comment: Read `man sudoedit` and set up the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables to point to your favorite editor.

Answer (score 0):

I found in the german wiki on gio the following command

```
gedit admin:///etc/fstab
```

The place admin:// seems to be designed for accessing with admin rights.